# query table every second for notification. Is it a good practice?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, notifications

I have a project that has notification functionality and I came up with an idea on how to get a notification real time. My idea is to query the table every second. I have a notification table, so whenever the client is adding something it will insert to the notification table and then the other client gets the notification by querying it. I use ajax to do this.

Is it good to query the table every second or it's bad programming practice? I only use this in localhost and it's fine. Do this kind of idea affect negatively when the site goes live?

thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: 100 client users querying the site/database every second is a fairly noticeable performance overhead on the servers

Answer (score 8):

Pinging the DB every second is not the ideal way to do this; you can implement a combination of DB triggers and HTML5 websockets/push notifications:
http://html5hacks.com/blog/2013/04/21/push-notifications-to-the-browser-with-server-sent-events/

http://www.abrandao.com/2013/06/25/websockets-using-modern-html5-technology-for-true-server-push/

http://pusher.com/tutorials/html5_realtime_push_notifications

Comment: Of course, WebSockets depends upon HTML5 support.  Techniques like Comet will keep long-lived AJAX requests open for push notifications without requiring HTML5.

Comment: And, as @eggyal implied, "HTML5 support" is not a clear blanket concept at this point: http://html5test.com/results/desktop.html

Answer (score -1):

1. Will this be used only by a very small number of clients? Or will this be a public website where there will be dozens of clients querying the DB? If it's more than just a handful of people, you don't want to do that. Instead, consider saving down the DB result statically (e.g. e locally saved JSON file) and have the clients access that.
2. Consider increasing the timeout. Are you sure that 1 second will really give you any advantage over, say, 10 seconds?
3. If you expect this to be many, many people, you'll want to look at another architecture that pushes data to your clients. I think [Meteor](http://www.meteor.com/) is brilliant, but there are multiple choices here.